# C++ with extern "C" in namespace prefix resolution and optimization level dependency

Tags: c++, c, linux

I have a file "test.cxx" with

```
namespace net {
    extern "C" {
#include <arpa/inet.h>
    }
}

int main() {
    htons(1024);
}
```

When compiling with **-O1** or more everything's fine.

When compiling with **-O0**:

```
error: ‘htons’ was not declared in this scope
suggested alternative: ‘net::htons’
```

Then I change **htons** to **net::htons**.

When compiling with **-O0** everything's fine.

When compiling with **-O1** or more:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

Reproduced that on gcc-4.9.2 and clang-3.7.0.
Can someone explain why does it happen?

Comment: Why are you including `inet.h` inside `namespace net`?

Comment: actually compilers and static analysers should warn whenever somebody tries to do that.

Answer (score 13):

It happens because at `-O0`, call is compiled to `htons` function and your declaration for this function is inside `namespace net`. In optimized version, `-O2` for example, call is replaced with a macro.

You can verify this by pre-compiling your program using `gcc -O0 -E` v/s `gcc -O2 -E`

**When htons is used**
At `-O2`, `htons` is translated to

```
int main() {
    (__extension__ (
       {
          register unsigned short int __v, __x = (unsigned short int) (1024);
          if (__builtin_constant_p (__x))
             __v = ((unsigned short int) ((((__x) >> 8) & 0xff) | (((__x) & 0xff) << 8)));
          else
             __asm__ ("rorw $8, %w0" : "=r" (__v) : "0" (__x) : "cc");       
          __v;
      }
    ));
}
```

Making the code not throw the resolution error.

> error: ‘htons’ was not declared in this scope

**When net::htons is used**

When you replace `ntohs` with `net::ntohs`, `ntohs` define is used / exposed for optimization and your pre-processed code look as:

```
int main() {
  net::(__extension__ ({... /* removed for Brevity */ ...}));
}
```

And hence the error

> error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token

**Why does it happen**
`htons` may be implemented as a function or a macro. If it is defined as macro, `htons` would work fine. But if it is defined as a function `net::htons` would work fine.

It appears at `-O1` or higher, header files expose macro versions instead of function.

**Possible solutions**

```
using namespace net;  // Not recommended
```

```
#ifndef htons  // Recommended
using net::htnos;
#endif
```

```
extern "C" { // Add all declarations in global space
#include <arpa/inet.h>
}
```